# com.lowagie.text.Table is missing in latest build of iTextSharp

Tags: c#-4.0, itext

I am using iText, and upgrading to the latest itextsharp.  My old code is looking for the class  com.lowagie.text.Table

Any idea where it went?  I do not see it in the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was removed a little over a year and a half ago, along with some other classes in the 5.0.0 release. See the [changelog](http://itextpdf.com/history/?branch=50&node=500). (bottom of the page)

Comment: Thank you.  I substituted with PdfPTable, which is almost identical.